# How to let openssl respond to http/s get directly from command line while listenning

Tags: command-line, openssl

How can I let the openssl s_server to reply to every http(s) request directly from the command line or the server it self (the server is using centOS)? is that possible?

from the -help command for the openssl s_server I see that there is the -HTTP flag which should be used for :

```
 -WWW          - Respond to a 'GET /<path> HTTP/1.0' with file./<path> 
 -HTTP         - Respond to a 'GET /<path> HTTP/1.0' with file ./<path>
                  with the assumption it contains a complete HTTP response.
```

is this could be the answer for my problem? if so and since I couldn't find any example how to use this flag, I would be really glad to know how to exactly use it.

the command that I'm trying to run is simple as:

```
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -msg
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Add `-accept 443 -HTTP`.

Comment: What exactly happened when you attempted that command, and what did you expect to happen by that?  If `s_server` successfuly gets up and says `ACCEPT`, you can make an HTTP request by opening `https://server:4433/` with your browser, then you can type in something on the command line to make a response to it.

Comment: Well I think I need to edit my question, I want to reply from a file so I don't writebthe response manually from the command line while listening..

Comment: That way I make the server reply automatically, or send the reply automatically without writing a script to do so.. I thought thats why the - HTTP flag ment to be for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `-WWW` or `-HTTP`, `s_server` acts as a static content HTTPS server using files in the current directory.  Here's my full set up for demonstration.

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -subj /CN=localhost
$ echo 'hello, world.' >index.txt
$ openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -WWW
Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
ACCEPT
```

`s_server` is now waiting for HTTPS requests on port 4433.  From another shell you can make a request to `s_server` using `curl`.

```
$ curl -kv https://localhost:4433/index.txt
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4433 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=localhost
*    start date: 2015-06-01 15:29:02 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-07-01 15:29:02 GMT
*    issuer: CN=localhost
*    SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET /index.txt HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:4433
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 ok
< Content-type: text/plain
< 
hello, world.
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):

$ curl -k https://localhost:4433/not-existence
Error opening 'not-existence'
140226499298960:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:169:fopen('not-existence','r')
140226499298960:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:172:
```

On each request `s_server` prints requested path and wait for the next request again.

```
FILE:index.txt
ACCEPT
```

If you want to run a script on requests (as CGI does), you might have to use another tool like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

```
$ echo 'echo "Your request is $(head -1)"' > server.sh
$ socat openssl-listen:4433,cert=cert.pem,key=key.pem,verify=0,reuseaddr,fork exec:"bash server.sh"
```

The result is:

```
$ curl -k https://localhost:4433/index.txt
Your request is GET /index.txt HTTP/1.1
```